# Mercurial HG Archive subdirectory for web deployment

Tags: mercurial, web-deployment-project

I've got a Mercurial repository that contains a subdirectory for design files and a sub directory for code files.

What's the best way for me to deploy the code subdirectories on my server, keeping it secure, without deploying the design files?

Comment: What do you mean by "secure"? Do you want the version history subset to go along?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you should have these in separate repos as Kyle pointed out, optionally, using sub repositories.

However, with your setup as is something like this might be all you need:

```
hg archive -X designDocs /path/to/deploymentDir
```

or if you need to transfer it first:

```
hg archive -X designDocs --type zip /path/to/newDeploymentArchive.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepositories) for the two subdirectories.